# Jquery animation works initially but when trying to undo the animation, it keeps bouncing back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am using jquery to animate a div but when I try to click on the icon to close it, the animation executes for the duration but then reverts back.

html:

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-items"><i class="fa fa-reply fa-2x"></i></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.flex-container{
    display: flex;
    width: 80vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 200px;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}
.flex-items{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
i{
    visibility: hidden;
    float: right;
}
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".flex-items").click(function(){
        $(this)
        .animate({
            width: '+=800px',
            height: '+=400px'},{
            duration: 300,
            ease: "linear"})
        .css("order", "1");

        i = $(this).children();
        $(i).css("visibility" ,"initial");
        currentFlexItem = $(this);
    });

    $("i").click(function(){
            $(".flex-items").animate({
            width: '300px',
            height: '300px'},{
            duration: 300,
            ease: "linear"});

    }).css("visibility", "hidden");
});
```

The idea I had in the jquery code was first, detecting whether the square (.flex-items) gets clicked on. Once the square is clicked on I animate the width and height (the order doesn't appear to have affect on the issue). I then have it detect if the i tag is clicked, once clicked, the idea was to "undo" the changes I initially made.

Is there a simpler way of doing this? I'm fairly new to jquery.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/Froy/pen/rxgmgg)

Comment: Thanks for linking a codepen, btw. Made understanding and answering your question a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `click` event is propagating to the parent container. Just take the event, and stop it propagating. This can be done with the plain javascript call to [Event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

```
$("i").click(function(evt){
    evt.stopPropagation();
    $(".flex-items").animate({
        width: '300px',
        height: '300px'},{
        duration: 300,
        ease: "linear"});
        $("i").css("visibility", "hidden");
});
```

Also, note that chaining the css method after the click method probably isn't what you want. You should put the css call inside the event callback.

Comment: Well, let me add some references for you :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it is bouncing back is because the "i" tag is inside the "flex-items" div since there is open animation is triggered on click of flex-items it will open fine but when you click on the "i" tag which is for closing close animation it is working later the flex item event is triggered again since your "i" tag is inside flex-items so move the

```html
<i class="fa fa-reply fa-2x"></i>
```

out of the flex items div it will work fine. and makes sure you show the i tag using a class or id reference your current code reference is

```html
 i = $(this).children();
        $(i).css("visibility" ,"initial");
```

this should be taken care of when you place the  `<i>` tag outside.